# EmberJS - testing input action on enter

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing

I have an EmberJS (2.5.0) component similar to the following:

```
{{input type="text" value=searchValue enter='handleSearch'}}
```

Basically, hitting enter on the input field should trigger the 'handleSearch' action. And in my component, so far I have this:

```
searchValue: null,
actions: {
  handleSearch() {
    var searchValue = this.get('searchValue');
    var submitSearch = this.get('submitSearch');
    console.log('Search term entered: ', searchValue);
    if (submitSearch) {
      submitSearch(searchValue);
    }
  }
}
```

And the component is called via:

```
{{my-component submitSearch=(action 'externalAction')}}
```

That all works fine and all, but I'm having trouble actually testing it.

Here's my integration test (pseudo-copied from [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_testing-actions)):

```
test('search input', function(assert) {
  this.set('externalAction', (actual) => {
    console.log('in external action');
    assert.equal(actual, 'hithere');
  });
  this.render(hbs`{{universal-header-search submitSearch=(action externalAction)}}`);
  this.$('input').val('hithere');
  this.$('input').change();
});
```

The problem is, my `handleSearch` action handler never gets triggered. So how do I get my `input` field to trigger the handler in my integration test? I've also tried `this.$('input').submit()` and `this.$('input').trigger('change')`, but neither seems to do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `this.$('input').change();` you are triggering the `change` event, not the `enter` event.

After a short research i haven't found a solution to trigger the enter event in integration tests.

You could solve this problem by using the keypress event instead and detect the enter button in your handler (the enter event doesn't exist in jQuery, so i think ember does the same). To get the event in your handler you can't use the ember input helper:

```
<input type="text" value={{searchValue}} onkeypress={{action "handleSearch"}} />
```

Your handler:

```
handleSearch(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13) { //check if enter button was pressed
    var searchValue = this.get('searchValue');
    var submitSearch = this.get('submitSearch');
    console.log('Search term entered: ', searchValue);
    if (submitSearch) {
      submitSearch(searchValue);
    }
  }
}
```

To trigger the keypress event in your integration-test just use

```
this.$('input').keypress();
```

Or to trigger keypress event with enter button

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //enter button code
e.keyCode = 13;
$('input').trigger(e);
```

Comment: I could not get this to work, I was able to get it to work by using the `keyup` event instead of the `keypress` event, as mentioned in [DenHaydash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425984/emberjs-testing-input-action-on-enter#answer-44393929). But I am using `insert-newline='handlSearch'` in my template.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same issue: I had to trigger "enter" event of Ember's (v.2.8) input component programmatically

```
{{input ... enter=(action "someAction")}}
```

After some reverse engineering I've found a solution

```
const e = Ember.$.Event("keyup");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;
Ember.$('input').trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert-newline="actionName"` of `input` helper which only trigger when you press `return`/`enter` key

```html
<input {{insert-newline="actionName"}}>
```